# Example of non-normal operator whose all eigenvalues are real

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Does there exist a non normal operator whose all eigenvalues are real.

Comment: For these kind of issues the basic nilpotent often applies: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to check $2\times2$ matrices

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}
$$

What can you say for
$$
B = A^*A-AA^*
$$